# I read the dictionary as if it were a novel

Tags: translation

In my mother tongue, we have an expression that I have translated to

> I read the dictionary as if it were a novel.

I think the meaning is easy to grasp by I wonder if there a more suitable translation.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't think of any equivalent figure of speech in English, but your translation made sense to me, at least.

Comment: So it is implying either that trying to learn everything in the dictionary by reading it cover-to-cover is a waste of time because you're not getting the best use of it (which would be looking up each word, as needed) - OR - that you're trying to put meaning to something that is not meant to be taken literally, i.e., a string of words in alphabetical order with no collective meaning between each other?

Comment: The expression in my mother tongue (Portuguese): "Eu li o dicionário como se fosse um romance"

Comment: What is the meaning of this in the original?

Comment: @KristinaLopez, It's more like the first option but not in the time wasting sense. Is not that you are trying to retain all of the content of the dictionary, but you will do retain a lot of definitions.

Comment: @Charles, [this article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/magazine/7654511.stm) is an excellent exemple of the meaning of the expression.

Comment: Well, maybe the term 'expression' is abusive. Actually, you can write it in lots of different ways. If the definition were to be in a dictionary it would look like:  
"To read something as if it were a novel: To read a book that was not conceived to be read continuously from cover to cover (e.g. a reference book), thoroughly, from cover to cover, in a relaxed way."  
Or: "Something that can be read as if it were a novel: A book that was not conceived to be read continuously from cover to cover (e.g.a technical book) but is written in an way that allows to read it enjoyably from cover to cover.

Comment: @Carlo_R., that's OK. Thank you.  
Lynn - which seems to be an native American speaker - couldn't find an equivalent figure of speech in English.

Comment: Translation is off topic per the [faq].

Comment: Helio, if you'd like this to be reopened, you should edit your questino and explain more thoroughly what the quote really means, what its connotations are, what situations you would use it in. Do you use it to describe a useless situation (' a woman needs a man like a fish needs a bicycle'), or how smart someone is, or how much they like to learn? Would you use it about yourself (as you've done in the OP), or as a compliment or insult about someone else? Or other things? Also, put those things in your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

"I read the dictionary from cover to cover." Novel is not appropriate because it is more likely that somebody read the dictionary thoroughly and diligently, rather than with great interest.

Comment: No. You are missing the point.

Comment: To be fair, it's hard to get the point, because many of us are not familiar with the expression. It's a fascinating quip, but I agree with @Mitch – we need some extra help trying to figure out how the expression is used, not just the literal meaning of the words.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. It had been a bummer to have been downvoted. Although, to be perfectly fair, the link to the BBC story that the OP posted in a comment did explain that the intended connotation was "with great interest" rather than throughly. Interesting words in the story btw. If nothing else, I deserved the downvote for even trying to answer! But hey, at least I answered my first question here :) Thank you again for your kind comment!